# Encoding issue , between windows and linux

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$data['rate_change_with'] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT', $data['rate_change_with']);
$rate_change_with_index_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $data['rate_change_with']);
```

on a windows machine it works perfectly. But on ubuntu 12.04 it breaks. preg_split has no effect.  $data['rate_change_with'] is something like

```
 3.3 (spaces/tabs)  4.5 (spaces/tabs) 6.5
```

Help please!

Thanks

Edit: the spaces and tabs are a 'different' type of space/newline characters mixture, and I am not sure what.
Edit2: Not sure if it will help , but here is a screenshot of the target in debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvSny.jpg

Edit3: actual sample: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7998366/de.html . The rightmost column is the issue

Edit4: changing `&nbsp;` to spaces doesn't help! what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: perhaps php needs something of system provided regex software... but I don't if that is the case...

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 11.04 with input `'3.3 4.5 6.5'`, output seemed correctly split. I very much doubt it would be broken between 11.04 and 12.04. Still, with the example input, the `iconv` will have no effect, as it includes only ASCII characters.

Comment: @lanzz thanks for testing, but the target string actually contains, some strange newlines/spaces.

Comment: Then you should provide an actual sample input that triggers the problem.

Comment: How do you extract that column from the HTML into  `$data['rate_change_with']`? There are `&nbsp;` entities between the numbers there, depending on your extraction method these could be preserved as actual HTML entities (thus not being whitespace at all) or converted to non-breaking space characters (`U+00A0`).

Comment: I am using the querypath library. But thanks, I'll just convert nbsp to spaces, that would help. right ?

Comment: Is there any way you can show us a hex dump of the bytes in the string after the `iconv()` call? Preferably both on the working and non-working platforms? EDIT here is a simple loop to do it: `for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($data['rate_change_with']); $i < $l; $i++) { printf("%02X ", ord($data['rate_change_with'][$i])); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$data['rate_change_with'] = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\-\./]", " ", $data['rate_change_with']) ;
$rate_change_with_index_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $data['rate_change_with']);
```

Basically I couldn't figure out the char that was present that was causing the problem, so the above simply removes all characters except for the whitelisted ones, thereby eliminating any strange characters that existed there.